Most efficient way of generating and storing Eloquent Model stats
I'm building an application where users can sign petitions - each petition would have a subject attribute and a location attribute. I would have a landing page for each subject, a landing page for each location and a landing page for each petition (subject+location combo). I have a Signature eloquent model with a signatures pivot table with columns user_id, subject_id, location_id.

On the landing page for each subject, I would like to display a headline like: "XX total signatures for [subject] across YY locations!"

On the landing page for each location, I would like to display a headline like: "XX total signatures for [location] across YY subjects!"

On the petition landing page (subject/location combination), I would like to display a headline like: "XX total signatures for [subject] in [location]!"

On the home page, I would like to display a headline like: "XX total signatures across YY subjects in ZZ locations!"


I was thinking to create a SignatureObserver which would increment or decrement the relevant values any time a signature is added or removed like this:
class SignatureObserver
{
    public function created(Signature $signature)
    {
        Cache::increment("total_signatures");
        Cache::increment("location_signatures:{$signature->location_id}");
        Cache::increment("subject_signatures:{$signature->subject_id}");
        Cache::increment("subject_location_signatures:{$signature->subject_id}:{$signature->location_id}");
    }

    public function deleted(Signature $signature)
    {
        Cache::decrement("total_signatures");
        Cache::decrement("location_signatures:{$signature->location_id}");
        Cache::decrement("subject_signatures:{$signature->subject_id}");
        Cache::decrement("subject_location_signatures:{$signature->subject_id}:{$signature->location_id}");
    }
}

I have not tested this just yet, but I'm wondering would this be the most efficient way of storing and accessing these stats? Would events/listeners be a better approach? Would it make sense to have a dedicated table for these stats? If I already have a bunch of signatures in the database OR if the cache is cleared - what would be the best way to call a re-count should the cache values be null at any point?

I would only cache fixed values (ex: country, languages etc..), not values that would change over time. Imagine 1k users online doing petitions that cache is useless.

@francisco so how would you approach calculating this data? Would you do it on the fly - running db count queries on every page load?

An observer increment/decrement when create()/delete() that aux table and broadcast that (you can listen with laravel-echo) and update the UI. Use index in the tables with the FK.

Sorry by aux table you mean create a dedicated stats table with an entry for each total that I need and have the observer increment/decrement those numbers? I don't need the numbers to update in real time on the front end so laravel-echo may be a bit more complexity than my application requires.

Ok, so if you don't need all that "real-time" data, I would do a schedule by each hour (24 times a day), to update the stats table, and you could forget the observer events (so you don't trigger events after each create/update). And use the cache to store the new stats table in command.
